# Best representation of a database table on memory and ways to query by line on python?

Tags: python, datatable

I have an XLS table I am parsing with python and currently I am representing that with a hash which has as key (line_number,column_number) -- in practice i am using other identifier but for the sake of simplicity this would work to explain the situation.

Now, say that I am interested on obtaining a given line of this table, I am using:

```
for k, v in self.table.iteritems():
    if k[0] == '1': 
        # do whatever
```

In other words I am visiting every cell and verifying its line, which didn't seem the best way to do this. I am not sure at this point if using a hash with partial keys would be the best way either. Of course, using a database would be probably the best option but given my dataset is very small, I would rather keep the program simple and just working with it on memory. Thus my question narrows down to:

1. Is there a better way to represent a table on memory on python?
2. How would I go about obtaining a line out of it? (Given the best representation)

I hope the question is pertinent. I wasn't able to find the appropriate keywords to search around this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've stored in-memory tables using arrays & lists from which you can call specific items based on position:

```python
array = [
  ['John', 19, 'male'], 
  ['Sara', 22, 'female'] 
]
```

Have you considered that?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

columns = ['col1', 'col2']
table = [
    ['abc', 123],
    ['def', 456],
    ['ghi', 123],
]

view = dict((name, defaultdict(list)) for name in columns)
for row in table:
    for i, col in enumerate(row):
        name = columns[i]
        view[name][col].append(row)

print view['col1']['abc']
print view['col2'][123]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify [Dugres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97198/dugres)' answer in order to provide access to the table by row, to use memory more efficiently and to try to make more natural use of the dict class.
In this example, the row keys are from a simple numeric enumeration, counting from 0.

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2']
table = [
    ['abc', 123],
    ['def', 456],
    ['ghi', 123],
]

# build view from a comprehension
view = {i: {columns[j]: table[i][j] for j in range(len(columns))} for i in range(len(table))}

# build view procedurally
view = dict()
for i, row in enumerate(table):
    view[i] = dict()
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        view[i][columns[j]] = col

# view contents
view
{0: {'col2': 123, 'col1': 'abc'}, 
1: {'col2': 456, 'col1': 'def'}, 
2: {'col2': 123, 'col1': 'ghi'}}


# Cell by row and column
>>> view[0]['col1']
'abc'

# List of cells for row 0:
>>> [view[0][col] for col in columns]
['abc', 123]

# All cells in col2:
>>> [view[row]['col2'] for row in sorted(view.keys())]
[123, 456, 123]

# All rows with value 123 in col2, using a list generator expression
[[view[row][column] for column in columns] for row in view.keys() for col in columns if view[row][col] == 123]
[['abc', 123], ['ghi', 123]]


# All rows with value 123 in col2, using a list generator function
def rowGenerator(view, col, value):
    for row in view.keys():
    if view[row][col] == value:
        yield [view[row][colName] for colName in columns]

>>> [row for row in rowGenerator(view, 'col2', 123)]
[['abc', 123], ['ghi', 123]]
```